# GLSL - Vertex normals + normal mapping?

Tags: vector, glsl, normals

I'm trying to create a simple shader for my lighting system. Right now, I'm working on adding support for normal-mapping right now. Without normal-mapping, the lighting system works fine. I'm using the normals forwarded from the vertex shader, and they work perfectly fine. I'm also reading the normals from the normal map correctly. Without including the normal map, the lighting works perfectly. I've tried adding the vertex normal and the normal map's normal, and that doesn't work. Also tried multiplying. Here's how I'm reading the normal-map:

```
vec4 normalHeight = texture2D(m_NormalMap, texCoord);
vec3 normals = normalize((normalHeight.xyz * vec3(2.0) - vec3(1.0)));
```

So I have the correct vertex normals, and the normals from the normal map. How should I combine these to get the correct normals?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you store your normal maps. If they are in world space to begin with (this is rather rare) and your scene never changes, you can look them up the way you have them. Typically, however, they are in tangent space. Tangent space is a vector space that uses the object's normal, and the rate of change in the (s,t) texture coordinates to properly transform the normals on a surface with arbitrary orientation.

Tangent space normal maps usually appear bluish to the naked eye, whereas world space normal maps are every color of the rainbow (and need to be biased and scaled because half of the colorspace is supposed to represent negative vectors) :)

If you want to understand tangent space better, complete with implementation on deriving the basis vectors, see [this link](http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html).

Answer (score 0):

Does your normal map not contain the adjusted normals? If yes, then you just need to read the texture in the fragment shader and you should have your normal, like so:

```
vec4 normalHeight = texture2D(m_NormalMap, texCoord);
vec3 normal = normalize(normalHeight.xyz);
```

If your trying to account for negative values then you should not be multiplying by the vector but rather the scalar.

```
vec3 normal = normalize( (normalHeight.xyz * 2.0) - 1.0 );
```